# Reduce Fails Silently

Tags: f#

I am seeing some strange behavior when using `Seq.reduce` as follows:

```
printfn "%d" (Seq.reduce (*) [1..1]) // 1
printfn "%d" (Seq.reduce (*) [1..5]) // 120
printfn "%d" (Seq.reduce (*) [1..10]) // 3628800
printfn "%d" (Seq.reduce (*) [1..50]) // 0 ???
```

The last example is failing to compute the product (probably due to overflow), but for some reason is still returning 0.

It seems like this should throw an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not `reduce` that fails silently, it is the multiplication operator that does not check for overflow. This one throws:

```
printfn "%d" (Seq.reduce Checked.(*) [1..50]) 
// System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

but this one does not:

```
printfn "%d" (Seq.reduce Operators.(*) [1..50]) // 0 ???
```

> This module contains the basic arithmetic operations with overflow
>   checks.

```
module Checked

  val ( ~- ): value:  ^T ->  ^T
  val ( - ): x:  ^T1-> y:  ^T2 ->  ^T3
  val ( + ): x:  ^T1-> y:  ^T2 ->  ^T3
  val ( * ): x:  ^T1-> y:  ^T2 ->  ^T3
  val byte: value:  ^T -> byte
  val sbyte: value:  ^T -> sbyte
  val int16: value:  ^T -> int16
  val uint16: value:  ^T -> uint16
  val int: value:  ^T -> int
  val int32: value:  ^T -> int32
  val uint32: value:  ^T -> uint32
  ...
```

Full name: Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.Checked

Assembly: FSharp.Core